# Shortcut for inserting environments in `org-mode`

Tags: emacs, key-binding, org-mode

I'm using `org-mode` for organizing myself (very useful so far!). However, it is kind of annoying writting

```
  #+begin_comment
  ...
  #+end_comment
```

each time I'd like to insert an environment.

**Question**

Is there a shortcut to insert the `#+begin_` and `#+end_` for a given environment?

In the same way `C-c C-o comment RET` would insert

```
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}
```

in `latex-mode`.

Comment: Do you have the package `yasnippet` installed?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19145433/1225607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

org-mode provides a [templating system](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html#Easy-Templates) to easily insert structural elements. Although far less featureful than yasnippet, it can come in handy.

The default templates don't include comment blocks, but you can easily add them by putting something like this in your init file:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
                '("C" "#+BEGIN_COMMENT\n?\n#+END_COMMENT" "")))
```

After this, you can easily insert comment blocks typing

```
<C
```

on a line by itself, then `<TAB>` to trigger the template expansion.